# How to see if device is Connected

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth

I have an application that I used to connect to external devices through Bluetooth, using the BLE-PLX library.

I have a problem during the scan and connect, because not always it works.

This is the code that I use to connect one device through Bluetooth:

```
// First Scan
    scans1() {
    this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
      if (error) {
          this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
          console.log("0.Error, retry connection.")
          this.scans1()
        //return;
      }
      if ((device.name == this.model_dx(this.props.Model)) || (device.name == this.model_sx(this.props.Model)))
      {
        this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
        console.log("1.Device Founded - ", device.name)
        this.setState({device1: device})
        this.manager.connectToDevice(device.id)
          .then(() => {
          console.log("2.Launch Scans 2") // this is for connect to the second device. 
          this.scan2();
          })
          .catch(() => {
          Alert.alert("Error " +  "Connection Failed.");
          Actions.homepage();
          })
      }
      else if ((device.name == null )) {
        this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
        console.log("3.Device is - null - retry scan")
        this.scans1();
      } else {
        this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
        console.log("4.Error: Device not found.")
        Actions.homepage();
      }
    });
```

Now what I would to know, how can I see if a device is connected or not? ( I don't know if could be another kind of error, I have tried to resolve any kind of problem).

Following the guide they said:

**Check connection state of a Device.**

```
isDeviceConnected(deviceIdentifier: DeviceId): Promise<boolean>
```

*Parameters*

`deviceIdentifier (DeviceId)` Device identifier.

*Returns*

```
Promise<boolean>:
```

Promise which emits true if device is connected, and false otherwise.

But I don't understand how can I use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

I can use:

```
this.manager.isDeviceConnected(device.id).then((res) => console.log(res))
```